# Gray lines hidding my texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

I applied a texture on a flat surface in blender. However, it is only partially visible because it is masked by gray lines, that move when I zoom in and out. It looks like a rendering issue. Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks[image]

Edit: on the back of the surface, the texture appears perfect! So strange[image]

Comment: Do you have a duplicate plane or mesh below the textured plane? Looks like Z-Fighting to me. Also depending on the scale of your scene,  if its very large try increasing your camera's range

Comment: Hi @Rug no I don't seem to have a duplicate plane or mesh below the textured plane (I checked my collections). I doubled the camera field of view bu I still can't zoom in without these grey lines appearing...

Comment: @Rug on the back of the plane, the texture appears without the grey lines!

Comment: Adjust your clip start and end in the view tab on the right of the 3d properties menu. If you can'st find another object in the same space in object mode, try finding something in edit mode with select link or selct all of it and merge(m)<Merge by distance.

Comment: I suspect you do have two planes, but both in the same object, which is why they're not showing up in the outliner.  If I'm right, when you edit the plane and select all it should show a number other than 4 for the number of vertices.

Comment: Hi @MartyFouts yes indeed sorry I didn't express myself correctly: it's a flattened cube, not a plain plane. So indeed there are more than 4 vertices. Somehow it looks like my texture is applied on the bottom side of the flattened cube, not on the top, that's what's weird.

Comment: @ZakNelson Hi, I set my clip start at 0.0001 and clip end at 1000m but it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Alright I think I founnd the solution but not the explanation to the issue: I deleted my mapping node and the problem got fixed! So something to do with scaling.